# STM32L4 No UART Message

Tags: stm32, uart, cortex-m4

I've been trying for the past 2 days to get the USART2 controller (pins PD5 & PD6) working on the STM32L476VG Discovery, which allows for UART communication over the ST-LINK cable. I'm using the ARM GNU tools to compile the project in Ubuntu in a VM, using ST-Flash to write to the board's flash. I've generate example init code using the STM32CubeMX software and using this in my own code. The code compiles and links successfully, but whenever I connect to the COM port using TeraTerm in Windows (I make sure the board is disconnected from Ubuntu), I never see any output. I've tried using the built-in HAL_UART_Transmit function, and have also tried using my own uart_putc function to write messages.

Here is my main.c:

```
#include "stm32l476xx.h"
#include "core_cm4.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_hal_uart_ex.h"
#include "uart.h"

volatile int32_t TimeDelay;
void SysTick_Handler (void);
void Delay (uint32_t nTime);
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
static void USART_Init(void);
static void HAL_UART_InitStruct(void);

int main() {
    // initialize systick clock
    SysTick_Config(10000);  //10 ms reload period

    // initialize test led (PE8)
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOEEN; 
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitLED;

    GPIO_InitLED.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    GPIO_InitLED.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP; //push-pull
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitLED);    

    // initialize usart params  
    HAL_UART_InitStruct();
    USART_Init();

    while(1) {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_8); //testing application load
        uart_putc(42, huart2.Instance);
        //HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "msg\r\n", 5, 0xFFFF);
        Delay(100);     
    };

}

void SysTick_Handler (void) {
    if (TimeDelay > 0)
        TimeDelay--;
}

void Delay (uint32_t nTime) {
    TimeDelay = nTime;  // nTime specifies the delay time length
    while(TimeDelay != 0);  // busy wait
}

static void HAL_UART_InitStruct(void){
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

    __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
static void USART_Init(void)
{

    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_7B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    HAL_UART_Init(&huart2);    
}

void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
    /* infinite loop */
    /* use gdb to find out why we're here */
    while (1);
}

#endif
```

Here is my uart_putc function in uart.c:

```
int uart_putc(int c, USART_TypeDef* USARTx){
    // check USARTx interrupt and status register, and TX empty flag
    while (!(USARTx->ISR & USART_FLAG_TXE));
    USARTx->TDR = (c & 0xff);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: What is your basis for thinking that "UART communication over the ST-LINK cable" is supported?   While it is possible to get program data over the SWD cable in a variety of ways, those don't use the target's USART.  If you mean that your SWD adapter additionally offers a USB<>logic serial adapter on other pins beside the SWD, then you should try probing those connections with a scope.

Comment: @ChrisStratton according to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9vUyRjtG3Y) the ST-LINK V2 functions as a virtual COM port that UART can be used over, by setting pins PD5 and PD6 to the uart alternate function, that's what I was basing my assumptions off.

Comment: Have you checked the physical UART TX line (D5 or D6) with an oscilloscope or logic probe to make sure that it is, in fact, a problem at the microcontroller?

Comment: @Selvek PD5 and PD6 don't have any breakout pins that allow probing of the signal :( pages 9 and 10 [here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/d1/84/86/4b/08/82/47/91/DM00172179.pdf/files/DM00172179.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00172179.pdf) show the pins and pads that are accessible on the board

Comment: @akivjh You can still probe it if you've got a steady hand :)  D5 is the 11'th pin from the bottom along the right edge of the chip.  Look at R34, to the right of the microcontroller.  Now look directly left from R34 and up one microcontroller pin.  It's got a big convenient via you can use to probe, although you typically need to carefully scrape the soldermask off the via using an exacto knife first.  Or, you can probe the pin directly, it's just harder.  The pins around that area are all IO pins, so you won't damage the chip if you short them accidentally.

Comment: @Selvek good point, but I think that's a lot of hassle and effort for something that's supposed to be a development board :/

Comment: @akivjh I disagree - you could have something messed up in your virtual comm port and spend hours trying to debug your code, only to find out that the code is working fine.  If you have access to an oscilloscope, it's well worth this 5 minute test.

Comment: @Selvek yep, that's a good point as well!

On another note, for anyone interested I was able to use the code posted [here](http://web.eece.maine.edu/~zhu/book/tutorials.php) under tutorial 4 with Keil and got the UART working, now I just need to see the discrepancy in my original code.